# Run query one after one(sequence ) using two different tables with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise, sequelize.js

I have two tables , one for user with username,password and id, and the other one with operations made by users, with username and a file. 
Once I obtain the userId from session , I make a query in the user table to know the username of the users. After that I take the username and make the query to the second table operations, in which i would like to retrive filename for the selected user.

I use sequelize , and the table are not connected with primary and foreign key , due to the fact that I can't modify the structure of the database. So my goal is to run the queries in sequence. Once the first finish , the second starts.
I will appreciate any kind of help. Thanks a lot.

```
 app.get("/dashboard", redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
 if (req.session.userId) {



 let  promise1= User.findOne({ where: { id: req.session.userId } })
 console.log('promise ' + promise1)

let userFound =  promise1.then(userFound =>{
    console.log( 'utente trovato 1 '+ userFound.username);


    Operations.findAll({where:{cliente:userFound.username}})
    .then(opFound => {
        console.log(opFound.filename); // return undefined
        return opFound.filename
        });

});



}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can user async/await for it, it will also reduce your lines of code.

```
 app.get("/dashboard", redirectLogin, async (req, res) => {  

 try {

    if (req.session.userId) {

      let userObj = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.session.userId } })
      let opFound = await Operations.findAll({ where: { cliente: userObj.username } });
      console.log(opFound.filename)
      return opFound.filename;

          }  
    } catch (err) {
        return err;   
       } 
     });
```

Comment: what if I need to console.log opFound.filename ?

Comment: you can log it before returning. `console.log(opFound.filename)`, i have edited the code for it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet.

```
app.get("/dashboard", redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
        if (req.session.userId) {
           return User.findOne({ where: { id: req.session.userId } })
           .then((user) => {
                return Operations.findAll({where:{cliente:user.username}})
           })
           .then((opFound) => {
                console.log(opFound.filename); // return undefined
                return opFound.filename
           })
        }
    });
```